# I have troubles with Shiny dashboardSidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I created my shiny dashboard sidebar like this
I linked `MenuItem` to `tabItem`, by `tabName` and in each tabItem I put `tabsetPanel`

I would like, when I choose group A, to be able to display the different panels that are the subgroups A1, A2, and A3. I would like to do the same for group B and its subgroups. I can't do it, because only the panels in group B are displayed. I would like to keep this dashboardSidebar architecture.

Here are below my scripts

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DASHBOARD"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem( "Group A",tabName = "gpA",
                               selectInput(inputId = "Var1",label="variable 1", choices = c("Total","cat1","cat2"),
                                                               selected="Total"),
                               selectInput(inputId = "Var2",label="variable 2", choices = c("Total","cat1","cat2"),
                                                               selected="Total")),
                     
                     menuItem("Group B",tabName = "gpB")
                     )
  
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(
        tabName = "gpA",
        fluidRow(box(selectInput(inputId = "Hospital1",choices = c(LETTERS),
                                 label = "Choice hospital 1"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE),
                 box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital2",choices = rev(c(LETTERS)),
                                 label = "Choice hospital 2"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE)),
        
        fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Sub group A2", 
                   box(leafletOutput("")),box(leafletOutput(""))
                                      ),
          tabPanel("Sub group A3", box(leafletOutput("")),
                   box(leafletOutput(""))),
          tabPanel("Concurrence", leafletOutput(""))
                                    ))
        ),
      
      tabItem(
        tabName = "gpB",
        fluidRow(box(selectInput(inputId = "Commune",choices = c(letters),
                                 label = "choice a Zip code"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE)),
        fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Sub group B1", 
                   leafletOutput("")
                   ),
          tabPanel("Sub group B2", 
                   leafletOutput(""))
                                    ))
        )
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using multiple `selectInput`s (sub items) within the first `sidebarmenu` item, you need to use `menuSubItem` (or `menuItem`) under that to use the `tabName`.  Here tabName `gpA1` is what you need to refer to in `dashboardBody`.  You cannot access the tabpanels with `gpA` when you have sub-items.  Try this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DASHBOARD"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                   sidebarMenu( id="tabs",
                     menuItem( "Group A", tabName = "gpA",
                               selectInput(inputId = "Var1",label="variable 1", choices = c("Total","cat1","cat2"),
                                           selected="Total"),
                               selectInput(inputId = "Var2",label="variable 2", choices = c("Total","cat1","cat2"),
                                           selected="Total"),
                               menuSubItem("My Group A", tabName="gpA1",   ###   <---- refer to this tabName in dashboardBody
                                           icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               ),
                     
                     menuItem("Group B",tabName = "gpB")
                   )
                   
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(
        tabName = "gpA1",
        fluidRow(box(selectInput(inputId = "Hospital1",choices = c(LETTERS),
                                 label = "Choice hospital 1"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE),
                 box(selectInput(inputId = "Hopital2",choices = rev(c(LETTERS)),
                                 label = "Choice hospital 2"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE)),
        
        fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Sub group A2", 
                   box(leafletOutput("")),box(leafletOutput(""))
          ),
          tabPanel("Sub group A3", box(leafletOutput("")),
                   box(leafletOutput(""))),
          tabPanel("Concurrence", leafletOutput(""))
        ))
      ),
      
      tabItem(
        tabName = "gpB",
        fluidRow(box(selectInput(inputId = "Commune",choices = c(letters),
                                 label = "choice a Zip code"),
                     width = 6,height = 70,
                     solidHeader = TRUE)),
        fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Sub group B1",
                   leafletOutput("")
          ),
          tabPanel("Sub group B2",
                   leafletOutput(""))
        ))
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]